# What changes should I make when reapplying for a UK Standard Visitor visa?

Tags: visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, standard-visitor-visas

I have applied for a UK Standard Visitor visa with my mother and have been refused. I want to reapply soon.

What changes should I make?

[image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE and please have a detailed look to the linked Q&A which IMHO should answers most if not all of your questions.

Comment: Hi, if you carefully read the linked question you will see everything you need to know in order to apply successfully.  If you think your question is different in some way, please edit it to ask a unique question. At the moment, your situation is a classic case where the linked question provides all the answers, thanks!  Click this http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab